# Sort multidimensional array by column value within a column

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

I have an array in PHP and I need to sort by a nested array inside of the array...

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => 1
            [earnest_money_due] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1000.00, 
                    [currency] => 'USD'
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => 2
            [earnest_money_due] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 200.00,
                    [currency] => 'USD'
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [project_id] => 3
            [earnest_money_due] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 900.00,
                    [currency] => 'USD'
                )
        )
```

Here's how I'm trying to sort it:

$records - this the array of records

$column - this is the the sortable column "earnest_money_due"

`$columns = array_column($records, $column);`

`array_multisort($columns, SORT_ASC, $records);`

I need to be able to sort by the [value] of the [earnest_money_due]. My code doesn't work because it's trying to sort an array, not a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```php
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'project_id' => 1,
        'earnest_money_due' => [
            'value' => 1000.00,
            'currency' => 'USD',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'project_id' => 2,
        'earnest_money_due' => [
            'value' => 200.00,
            'currency' => 'USD',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'project_id' => 3,
        'earnest_money_due' => [
            'value' => 900.00,
            'currency' => 'USD',
        ],
    ],
];

array_multisort(
    array_map(
        static function ($element) {
            return $element['earnest_money_due']['value'];
        },
        $array
    ),
    SORT_ASC,
    $array
);

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Great answer. In all other questions, nested arrays consisted of only 2 levels, which can solved by passing array_column into array_multisort. This works for all levels as long as you step into the level you want with the custom function.

Comment: Doesn't my answer already explain this? @Blenzus

Comment: @mickmackusa It does, you explained it well, I already upvoted both answers.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `SORT_ASC`, then your code works just fine.  This is because PHP will sort your subarray as expected with it removed.  It will compare from the start of the subarray. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/M13k7))

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'earnest_money_due'), $array);
```

If that seems too hacky, unreliable, or unintuitive, `array_map()` is fine. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gBigv))

```
array_multisort(array_map(fn($row) => $row['earnest_money_due']['value'], $array), $array);
```

There is also nothing wrong with using `usort()`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CpKV5))

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => $a['earnest_money_due']['value'] <=> $b['earnest_money_due']['value']);
```

---

Regardless of which `array_multsort()` technique you use, you don't need to explicitly use `SORT_ASC` because this is the default sorting order.